# Update a field, depending on another field, in MongoDB documents (with Mongoose in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

I have a collection named `Article` in MongoDB database, with the following schema and model:

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
   site: String,
   date: String, 
   day: String, 
   link: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index: {unique:true}    
 });

var Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
```

An example of document, which has no `day` field yet:

```
[ { site: 'www.atlantico.fr',
    date: '2014-05-27T11:10:19.000Z',
    link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html',
    _id: 538473817eb00f082f4803fc,
    __v: 0} ]
```

I want, for all the documents of this collection, to update the `day` field, depending on the `date` field (in a given way that I know).

I tried that:

```
Article.find() // all documents
.exec(function (err, articles) { // articles is an array

    for (var i=0; i<articles.length; i++) { // for each document

        var myDate = articles[i].date; // I take its date
        myDate = myDate.replace(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*$/, '$3/$2/$1'); // I create a new variable 

        Article.update({date: articles[i].date}, // articles with this date
                       {day : myDate }, // update with the new variable created using the date
                       function(err, numberAffected){  
        });                           
      }
});
```

If I run this code for a given document (by putting a condition like `{link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html'}` in `Article.find()`, it works.

But if run the code showed above, that is supposed to do the job for all the documents, there must be a problem, because then I can see that all the documents have not been updated.

What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html and I tried this:

```
Article.find({}, function (err, articles) {    
    for (var i=0; i<articles.length; i++) {            
        Article.findOne({ link: articles[i].link }, function (err, doc){
            doc.day = doc.date.replace(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*$/, '$3/$2/$1');
            doc.save();
        });      
     }  
});
```

It seems to work.

But I don't know if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the fields in the document when updating.
The answer you have posted seems to be the way to go. 
Refer to this answer
[Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)